# Can you Send text message Automatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to know whether I can send text message on desire time automatically. The sending time of message and receiver mobile number is set by user some time before.
Please give me some code or links if it possible any way...thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with the official SDK, since you have to display the [`MFMessageComposeViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html).

If you would do it server side you would be able to do it, but you would most likely have to pay for the SMSes you send.